# how do i put a mileage 'block' on the obd11 connector?

Tags: vw, obd-ii, beetle

how do I stop my vehicles data from being transmitted to the obd11 connector under the dash, is there a single pin that can be removed/disconnected that will do this?
(VW new beetle 2001)

Comment: I just want to block (or make the mileage not readable) doesn't matter if the whole socket is made null and void, will replace whatever I change later replacing the obd11 port and putting in a dummy one not viable as cant get a replacement from a scrap yard where I am

Comment: The vehicle mileage will be displayed on the dashboard so anyone with access to the OBD 2 port will be able to simply read it from the odometer.  Why are you hoping to mask the mileage?

Comment: To all those who are wondering, I'd suspect the OP has to include some sort of insurance forced reader which would then state the mileage to the insurance company. If so, the OP is trying to skirt the milage which would be getting transmitted to the reader. There is absolutely no way to do this. The odometer can be read through the CANBus through (hex) PID A6. It is a standard PID, so would believe it should be available through almost all OBDII vehicles.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 So even if I had a method, I would not divulge it...

Comment: I've worked with a number of insurers who manufacture these "black boxes" and they all almost exclusively use GPS data to calculate mileage.

Comment: Good point @SteveMatthews, it's not just a measurement of mileage but speed and driving habits in some cases.

Comment: To whomever has downvoted this question, I'd like to remind the question itself is a good question. The intent probably isn't that good, but we shouldn't judge a question on intent, but rather content.

Comment: thank you Paulser for your comment, the subject is still open to an answer if you have one

Answer (score 2):

Data is not transmitted to the OBD 2 connector port, this is an interface which allows you to plug diagnostic equipment into the wiring loom of the car.

You could conceivably remove the port from the loom, i.e. make the port dead, but it would be far easier (and have the same effect) to unplug the device from the port.

Interesting side-note, the mileage is not actually available via standard OBD 2 diagnostics on a VW Group cars.  It is possible to access the number of revolutions that the wheel speed sensors have observed and then work out a calculation to see how close the odometer reading is.

What problem is it that you're hoping to solve?

Comment: It may be worth pointing out explicitly how bad an idea making the port non-functional would be @SteveMatthews, just in case.

Comment: Absolutely.  At best, it would render the car much harder to work on.  At worst, in parts of the world such as certain states in the US, it would cause the car to fail the state required vehicle inspection.